# WAT timezone causing W3C validator to claim RSS is invalid

Tags: xml, rss, timezone, validation, w3c

I have an XML file for event information.  There is an entry for Abuja, Nigeria.  Everything that I've seen says that the time zone abbreviation is WAT.  But, the [w3 feed validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flcbranson.org%2Frss%2FEvents.xml) says that it's invalid.  If I replace WAT with CST, it validates.  It seems like the problem is strictly with that time zone.

W3 Feed Validator Results:

```
Sorry
This feed does not validate.
line 106, column 41: pubDate must be an RFC-822 date-time: Fri, 01 Nov 2013 16:00:00 WAT [help]
<pubDate>Fri, 01 Nov 2013 16:00:00 WAT</pubDate>
```

XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:xxx="http://www.xxx.org/">
    <channel>
        <title>Upcoming Events</title>
        <link>http://www.xxx.org</link>
        <description></description>
        <atom:link href="http://www.xxx.org/rss/Events.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <item>
            <title>xxx</title>
            <xxx:host>Hosted by xxx</xxx:host>
            <xxx:speaker>Speaking: xxx</xxx:speaker>
            <dc:creator>xxx</dc:creator>
            <pubDate>Fri, 01 Nov 2013 16:00:00 WAT</pubDate>
            <xxx:extraDate1>Sat, 02 Nov 2013 16:00:00 WAT</xxx:extraDate1>
            <xxx:extraDate2>Sun, 03 Nov 2013 07:00:00 WAT</xxx:extraDate2>
            <xxx:endDate>Sun, 03 Nov 2013 15:00:00 WAT</xxx:endDate>
            <link>http://www.xxx.org</link>
            <xxx:venue>xxx</xxx:venue>
            <xxx:address>xxx</xxx:address>
            <xxx:location>xxx</xxx:location>
            <xxx:zip></xxx:zip>
            <xxx:phone>xxx</xxx:phone>
            <xxx:notes></xxx:notes>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

That XML is edited down, for brevity.  I've had multiple American time zones, but this is the first foreign time zone.

The file works with RSS readers and I have a PHP page that works with it.  The problem is that I'm working with some JavaScript and it's throwing up an invalid XML error.

Is there actually something wrong with `<pubDate>`?  I don't see it, if there is.

Comment: Follow th link in the error message - you get to the rfc which lists all the timezones it understands and WAT is not listed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spec is pretty clear:

http://asg.web.cmu.edu/rfc/rfc822.html#sec-5.1

```
 zone        =  "UT"  / "GMT"                ; Universal Time
                                             ; North American : UT
             /  "EST" / "EDT"                ;  Eastern:  - 5/ - 4
             /  "CST" / "CDT"                ;  Central:  - 6/ - 5
             /  "MST" / "MDT"                ;  Mountain: - 7/ - 6
             /  "PST" / "PDT"                ;  Pacific:  - 8/ - 7
             /  1ALPHA                       ; Military: Z = UT;
                                             ;  A:-1; (J not used)
                                             ;  M:-12; N:+1; Y:+12
             / ( ("+" / "-") 4DIGIT )        ; Local differential
                                             ;  hours+min. (HHMM)
```

You need to use the local differential (in this case `+0100`)

Comment: Store everything in UTC. It'll make your life easier. Only worry about timezones when interfacing with humans.

Comment: Ok...I saw that in the spec, yesterday.  I followed a link from the [RSS spec page](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html).  I didn't see that it ONLY worked with those time zones.

Comment: @Thanatos I have considered doing that, in the past.  The problem that I've had is that, when I do server-side code, it interprets it as the time zone that the server is in.  Also, JavaScript (I think) interprets it as the time zone that the user is in.  In this particular instance, I want the user to see the actual time and time zone designation (not the server's or user's variant of that time).  Unfortunately, using an offset doesn't give the ability to determine a time zone (is +0100 WAT, BST, CET, IST, etc...).  Especially when you consider daylight saving time, it can be a big deal.

Comment: @doubleJ dealing with dates and timezones is a mess.  There are libraries like https://github.com/mde/timezone-js that try to ease the pain and https://github.com/moment/moment that try to completely wrap Date

Comment: @doubleJ: IIRC, JS has support for converting to/from UTC/local. (But it has no way to determine *what* TZ the user is in.) Server side, just don't rely on the server's TZ. It depends on the language of course, but some offer easy access to converting from/to UTC and an arbitrary TZ.